# Listen to react-native event in Android code

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to find a way with which I can listen to an event that is triggered in Javascript code. Currently I am using `RCTDeviceEventEmitter`  to emit events but there was no function in it to create a listener in native code. I tried looking for other ways but could not find any yet.
Using an event is not necessary, I want to follow the best practice here so if there is another way please suggest.

How is communication done from React-native to Android generally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used React callbacks in native modules to do this. Seems like the right thing to use.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#callbacks